# Can we zip a directory in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was thinking if it is possible to zip a directory on hdfs and then bring it on to the local system. Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by zip a file like a result file from HDfS??

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Hive table & do an insert overwrite after setting the following properties :

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
set io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
```

But a better approach is to enable compression in the job which creates the files in the first place.

NOTE : Although i specified compression as Gzip it is better to use some splittable codec like snappy or lzo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am trying to zip a directory here. Not a file.